# How to pass the structure to a function in C++ defined in another class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a class Con as this:-

```
class Con
{
 public:
  struct MachineList
  {
    BSTR AccountId;
    BSTR MachineId;
    BSTR Make;
    char* Make1;
    BSTR Model;
    char* Model1;
    BSTR SerialNumber;
    BSTR IpAddress;
    char* IpAddress1;
    BSTR Port;
    int Port1;
    BSTR LocationCode;
    } machinelist[100] ;
   int w;
 } ;
```

i created an object of `Con` class as `Con m_con;`

I have another class `Test`

```
class Test
{
 public:
  void fun();//i want to pass the object of the structure that i created in Con
  //what arguments should i pass in fun function?
};
```

Comment: "the object of the structure that i created in Con"  What?  You want to pass the array of Machines?  You want to pass a machine?  You want to pass the whole `Con` object?  Do you want the function to have a copy of the parameter, or a reference, or a pointer?  Please edit the question to be clearer as to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Con {
public:
   struct Machine {
      BSTR  AccountId;
      BSTR  MachineId;
      BSTR  Make;
      char* Make1;
      BSTR  Model;
      char* Model1;
      BSTR  SerialNumber;
      BSTR  IpAddress;
      char* IpAddress1;
      BSTR  Port;
      int   Port1;
      BSTR  LocationCode;
   };
   typedef Machine Machines[100];

   Machines machines;
   int      w;
};

/**
 * passing a reference to a single machine, which fun might change
 */
void fun0( Con::Machine & machine );

/**
 * passing a reference to a single machine, which fun cannot change
 */
void fun1( const Con::Machine & machine );

/**
 * passing a reference to the entire array of machines, which fun may change
 */
void fun2( Con::Machines & machines );

/**
 * passing a reference to the entire array of machines, which fun cannot change
 */
void fun3( const Con::Machines & machines );
```

I don't understand which version of fun you want so I have made four...

Comment: not that it matters (especially since the code seems to be for Windows judging from the type BSTR (COM uses a type by this name)), but posix reserves names ending in `_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to pass the whole `machinelist` array?

```
void fun(const Con::MachineList (&argument)[100] );
```

But easier would be to typedef it:

```
class Con { 
 public:
    struct MachineList{ ... };
    typedef MachineList (Machines)[100];

    Machines machines;
};
```

and use

```
void fun(const Con::Machines& m);
```

To be called like:

```
Con c;
fun( c.machines );
```

Comment: i did what you said that typedef one but getting an error that is error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int error C2751: 'Con::machines' : the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

Comment: I, on the other hand, copy-pasted this literal example into codepad.org, and it ran without a fuzz.

Comment: But as you may know, C++ _is_ case-sensitive.  So `Machines` is not the same as `machines`.

Comment: I realized I didn't show you how to use the function - added that example.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
public:
void fun(Con::MachineList);
};

Test t;
Con c;
t.fun(c.machinelist[0]);
```

Currently the Con::MachinList type looks like it's not appropriate for copying, so you should either define appropriate constructors and assigment operators or you should pass by reference by declaring `fun` as `void fun(Con::MachineList const &);` instead of as I show above.

Also MachinList probably needs an appropriate destructor...

Comment: I don't think he should be copying `BSTR`s.

Comment: well, the type doesn't have a destructor either, so the type shouldn't own any resources... copying would be fine if this definition of it is correct, though I'd bet you're right and the definition of MachineList is not appropriate for how it's actually used.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7(v=vs.71).aspx `BSTR` owns resources.

Comment: but the struct doesn't own the BSTR. BSTR is just a pointer to resources which (assuming the struct is correctly defined) are owned and managed elsewhere. So copying a pointer to that resource should be fine.